# Richfaces tree selfdrop

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces

i got a tree

```
<rich:tree acceptedTypes="menu">
   <rich:treeNode dragType="menu" acceptedTypes="menu,article">
       menu
   </rich:treeNode>
   <rich:treeNode dragType="article" acceptedTypes="none">
       aricle
   </rich:treeNode>
</rich:tree>
```

and i got a tree like this:

```
 + menu 1
   + article 1
 + menu 2
   + article 2
```

I got two problems here now:

1. If i click on menu 1 too slowly, a dragdrop-event is started instead of an selection-event.
2. If i try to drag-drop menu1, i dont like to be able to drag menu1 to menu1.

Now my question is:

can i manipulate the dropabillity more preciesly?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct implementation? Is it okay if I ask you more about how you want it to behave?

Comment: Yes, i am sure, there is a Dragdroplistener who works well. Sorry, i am not able to give more specific information about the behave because i dont know how to calculate when the drag is starten (may the time, the user press-down the lmb, may the distance between the pixel the user need to initial-drag the item to give an real drag-event, may a combination of both ....), guess this would be an new question. There must be a already implemented function.

Comment: Which version of richfaces are you using?

Comment: Same question, what version is it?

Comment: Now im on-location, its the version 3.3.3-final (http://78.47.31.226:8080/umweltgewerkschaft/versionsnummer-info.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

The latest richfaces library has a demo, may be the demo implementation will help you. The demo does not behave like you have mentioned.
http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=tree&skin=blueSky

Since you are using version 3.3.3 the below link might help you
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tree.jsf?tab=dnd&cid=144111

Comment: none of the demos has anything to do with drag-drop-treenodes.

Comment: Well, your edit is mutch better. But the link shows the problem i actually have with part 1 of my question, not the solution.

Comment: if you can put what you have done into a http://jsfiddle.net/ post we can see what exactly you mean is happening, otherwise its a bit unclear whats wrong